# Configure mod_jk with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache

Is there any way to configure both mod_jk and .htaccess in a same call
what are the steps follow plz replay me

httpd.conf

ServerAdmin "webmaster@vpaycash.in"
   ServerName www.vpaycash.in
   MIMEMagicFile /dev/null
   CustomLog logs/vpaycash.in_access_log "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b\"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""
   ErrorLog logs/vpaycash.in_error_log

DocumentRoot "/home/vpaycashinadmin/webapps"
   
       Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       AllowOverride All

JkMount /* wlb

JkMount /*.faces wlb

JkMount /*.html wlb

JkMount /*.iface wlb

JkMount /*.jspx wlb

JkMount /TestFilter wlb

JkMount /block/* wlb

JkMount /xmlhttp/* wlb
   Alias /usage "/home/vpaycashinadmin/public_html/usage"
   
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all

.htacess

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index.html$  index.iface

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether you can move the mod_rewrite configuration from .htaccess to httpd.conf, then yes.  Just add a beginning slash to your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^/index.html$ /index.iface
```

And put your mod_rewrite configuration in httpd.conf.